# Microsoft/Azure OAuth failing, my organization lacks a service principal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, bing-ads-api, azure-oauth, microsoft-oauth

I've been trying to use the Bing Ads API, but can't even make it past the first step. I've followed [these steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/advertising/guides/authentication-oauth?view=bingads-13) to the letter, but am getting stuck at the part where I need to ask for user consent.

I've created an app, and copied all the details down. I've created a URL that looks like this:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
?client_id={client_id}
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080
&response_mode=query
&scope=openid%20offline_access%20https%3A%2F%2Fads.microsoft.com%2Fmsads.manage
&state=1234
```

I've also tried adding in client_secret as a param, even if it's not mentioned in the docs, and that didn't work either.

However, I keep getting back this error message:

```
error = invalid_client
error_description = AADSTS650052: The app is trying to access a service 'd42ffc93-c136-491d-b4fd-6f18168c68fd'(Microsoft Advertising API Service) that your organization 'xxxxxx' lacks a service principal for. Contact your IT Admin to review the configuration of your service subscriptions or consent to the application in order to create the required service principal.
```

I've just created the Azure account for the first time (and this is my first experience with Azure, usually I work with GCP or rarely AWS), and I'm the only account that's created anything.

This error message is coming back as parameters appended to the redirect URL, I don't even make it to the Microsoft login page. `(http://localhost:8080/?error=invalid_client&error_description=AADSTS650052%3a+The+app+is+trying+to+access+a+service+%27d42ffc93-c136-491d-b4fd-6f18168c68fd%27(Microsoft+Advertising+API+Service)+that+your+organization+%27xxxxxxx7+lacks+a+service+principal+for.+Contact+your+IT+Admin+to+review+the+configuration+of+your+service+subscriptions+or+consent+to+the+application+in+order+to+create+the+required+service+principal.%0d%0aTrace+ID%3a+387accd1-d7a4-4ec2-b739-6cba07e23702%0d%0aCorrelation+ID%3a+a7def78f-5c49-4ede-b7d4-fc65d5ac75bc%0d%0aTimestamp%3a+2022-11-10+16%3a15%3a03Z&error_uri=https%3a%2f%2flogin.microsoftonline.com%2ferror%3fcode%3d650052&state=1234#)`

The weird thing is I've done the same exact thing above for a client at the same time, and with them I managed to get to the consent page.

Answer (score 4):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I registered one Azure AD application and granted **API permissions** like below:

[image]

To get **authorization code**, I executed **same request** as you in the browser and got **same error** as below in address bar:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
?client_id={client_id}
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080
&response_mode=query
&scope=openid offline_access https://ads.microsoft.com/msads.manage
&state=1234
```

**Response:**

[image]

To confirm whether it's the **same error** or not, I copied it in Notepad and checked the **full error** like below:

[image]

To **resolve** the error, you need to add **`msads.manage`** permission of *Microsoft Advertising API Service*.

Note that, you need to have **Microsoft Advertising account** to use Bing Ads API. If not, **sign up** for it in this [Microsoft Advertising](https://ads.microsoft.com/?fdmkt=en-in&fdiso=us&fdtz=-8.000)  website with your Azure AD account like below:

[image]

After completing the sign-up, you can find **`Microsoft Advertising API Service`** here:

[image]

Now, you can add **`msads.manage`** permission to your application like below:

[image]

Now when I ran the **authorization request** again in browser, I got consent screen successfully like below:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
?client_id={client_id}
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080
&response_mode=query
&scope=openid offline_access https://ads.microsoft.com/msads.manage
&state=1234
```

**Response:**

[image]

After accepting the consent, I got **authorization code** in the address bar like below:

[image]

Using the above **code**, you can generate access tokens for your application.

Comment: Thanks for the detail here, this is awesome! Unfortunately I'm working through the steps but getting stuck at the adding the API service part - this was definitely the issue as I hadn't done it. However, it's not showing up here. I'm not sure what to do, our ads account is connected to my main email (name@domain.com), but it says our primary domain is name.onmicrosoft.com. do i need to create a new ads account with that email? seems weird as it's not actually going to be linked to the advertising account we use day to day

Comment: Do you have any custom domain with `name@domain.com`? Have you added that custom domain to Azure AD? If not, try to add it to your Azure AD tenant by referring this [MsDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/add-custom-domain)

Comment: I did do that, although I only did it very recently - should I expect it to take some time to come through?

Comment: What the status of your custom domain? Is it showing as verified or unverified?

Comment: it's showing as verified

Comment: Try to make your `custom domain` as **primary domain** by referring this [MsDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/domains-manage#set-the-primary-domain-name-for-your-azure-ad-organization)

Comment: Done, still nothing - although maybe it takes some time to propagate? 2 other things worth mentioning:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249707/discussion-between-sridevi-and-jul).

Comment: I'm having the same problem as OP, was going to try to add the permissions manually in the manifest, but I can't find the resourceAccess id that's needed to match "msads.manage." Are you able to see what this value is, since you were able to add the permissions yourself?